# Adding to a stack from a map

Tags: java, dictionary, stack, shortest-path

I am working on a project for school that requires us to find the shortest path between two points. Basically I use a breadth first search to traverse the graph and then use a map to keep track of each cities predecessor. My idea is then that when I reach the end I will then use the edges map to find out how a city was gotten to and essentially work backwards. However when I attempt to pull values from the map all I get is null, even though when I print out the contents it shows that there is something there. If somebody could help me track down the problem I would appreciate it.

Contents of input file with each city and its neighbor:

```
basic
Bismark      Fargo
Minneapolis  Chicago
StPaul       Chicago
Minneapolis  StPaul
Minneapolis  Fargo
Fargo        GrandForks
```

The code *(corrected version, so this code won't exhibit the described problem any more):*

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BFSBasics {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Map<String, List<String>> graph = new HashMap<>();
        openFile(graph, args[0]);
        String start = args[1];
        String end = args[2];

        BFS(graph, start, end);
    }

    public static void openFile(Map<String,List<String>> graph, 
            String file) 
            throws FileNotFoundException{
        Map<String,List<String>> aGraph = new HashMap<>();
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(file))){
            if(!scan.next().equals("basic")){
                System.err.println("File cannot be read.");
                System.exit(1);
            }else{
                while(scan.hasNext()){
                    String city1 = scan.next();
                    String city2 = scan.next();
                    addEdge(graph, city1, city2);
                    addEdge(graph, city2, city1);                   
                }   
            }   
        }
    }

    private static void addEdge(Map<String, List<String>> graph, String city1,
            String city2){
        List<String> adjacent = graph.get(city1);
        if(adjacent == null){
            adjacent = new ArrayList<>();
            graph.put(city1, adjacent);
        }
        adjacent.add(city2);
    }

    public static void BFS(Map<String, List<String>> graph, String start,
            String end) {
        boolean done = false;
                //cities that still need to be worked on
        Queue<String> work = new ArrayDeque<>();
                //cities that have already been seen
        Set<String> seen = new HashSet<>();
                //cities predecessor i.e. how it was gotten to
        Map<String, String> edges = new HashMap<>();
        LinkedList<String> path = new LinkedList<>();

        String city = start;
        work.add(start);
        while (!done && !work.isEmpty()) {
            city = work.remove();
            for (String s : graph.get(city)) {
                if (!seen.contains(s)) {
                    edges.put(s, city);
                    work.add(s);
                    seen.add(s);
                    if (s.equals(end)) {
                        done = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Work backwards through the edges map and push onto the path stack
        path.push(end);
        String temp = edges.get(end);
        while(!temp.equals(start)){
            path.push(temp);
            temp = edges.get(path.peek()};
        }
        path.push(start);
        //print out the path
        while(!path.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(path.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your dataset? It's possible that the end node isn't reachable from the start node, which would explain your error.

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: What Hbcdev said. If end is not reachable from start, then there will be no edge from it to any node that is reachable from  start, thus edge.get(end) will be null.

Comment: are edges bidirectional?  if they are the graph is entirely connected.  I would like to see the code where you actually create the graph list.

Comment: Yes, the graph is undirected and unweighted. I have posted the entire program for your viewing.

Comment: Ok, may as well ask b/c it's still working for me, what are you command line args?

Comment: +1 to @jeff: works for me as well (see my answer), so command line arguments remain the most likely cause of this issue.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond. I have been able to track down the problem and I have adjusted the code above with my answer. As was pointed out by MvG I was not accessing the map and pushing the cities on the stack appropriately. In my original code I was looking ahead to far and thus getting the NullPointerException. Thanks to everyone for there help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with your path building code:

```
path.push(end);                 // push node (n - 1)
String temp = edges.get(end);   // temp = node (n - 2)
while(!temp.equals(start)){
    path.push(edges.get(temp)); // push node (n - 3) down to and including node 0
    temp = path.peek();         // temp = node (n - 3) down to and including node 0
}
path.push(start);               // push node 0
```

So the node (*n* - 2) will never be pushed to the path, whereas the node 0 will be pushed twice.

But except for this, the program works for me. So perheaps you really have an unreachable target, as [Hbcdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/705048/hbcdev) suggests. You should check whether or not you actually reached the end node. Note that your graph datra structure models a *directed* graph, so if you want to interpret your input as *undirected* edges, you'll have to insert two directed edges for each line of input.

Also note that you don't mark the initial node as seen, whereas all other nodes will get marked as seen when you add them to the queue. You should mark the first as well.

**Edit:**
After you pasted your (almost) complete code, I fixed it in the following ways:

- added two wildcard imports, for `java.util.*` and `java.io.*`. Wildcard imports are quick and dirty.
- Added a closing `}` at the very end to close the class definition.
- Added a line with the word `basic` to your input data. You really should `System.exit(1)` in case of that keyword missing, instead of continuing with inconsistent state.

With those modifications, I tested all possible combinations of two cities, always in both orders, and including paths form a city to itself. No evidence of `null` values anywhere, neither in output nor as a cause of printed exceptions.

Comment: I think I see my problem now. I was handling the stack incorrectly. Also thanks for the tip on  system.exit(1)

Comment: @Eric, don't forget to share your insights once you have confirmed them. Either accept a suitable answer, or write your own. We are all hoping to learn what went wrong for you that wouldn't go wrong for others like myself or jeff.

Answer (score -1):

I see a couple of possible problems here. The immediate cause may be this: Your logic implicitly assumes that there is only one way to reach any given node. While this may be true, I doubt it. If there are two ways to reach the same node, you overwrite the first with the second in your map.

For example, suppose the input was:

```
A->B
C->B
B->E
D->E
```

You want to get from A to E. It could be done by going A, B, E. But when you build your map, you'll create an edge entry for B, A. Then you'll write B, C, overwriting B, A. Then you write E, B. Fine. Then you write E, D, overwriting E, B. So when you're done, all that's in the edge map is (B, C) and (E, D). You then try to walk backwards from E. You find E, D. But this is wrong: you wanted E, B, but that got overwritten. When you try to find an entry for D, there is none, so it's impossible to get back to A.

A second problem is that you said that the goal was to find the SHORTEST path from start to end. But you're doing nothing to find the shortest path: you stop looking once you find any path. You really need to, in principle, find all possible paths and then select the shortest from that list. (Or hopefully, eliminate longer paths as you go, one way or another.)

Comment: I believe you're mistaken. As every node will get marked `seen` once it was visited, therer will only ever be one predecessor to every node. No overwriting. And as [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) visits paths in order of non-decreasing hop count, shorter paths will be encountered first. So the first found path will be the shortest one, in terms of hop count. Geographical distances are a different issue, but apparently not part of this question.